# How to get Liferay DXP current user information from angular 2+ app?

Tags: angular, liferay

I have an angular portlet in Liferay DXP. 
I can get Liferay current user info in view.jsp file.
How to get it from angular 2+ app (from app.component.ts for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

- You can pass the info at bootstrap time of angular.
- You can look at themeDisplay object. It's a global JS object so it will be available also in angular app.
- You can create an endpoint that will provide you user data over an AXAJ call.
- You can create your own global JS object similar to the ThemeDisplay and populate it with data that you need.